# Pass url arguments with link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.11

I didn't see anything in the Rails UrlHelper API about this, but I'm sure it's trivial (I'm still learning Rails).

I need to generate a URL using `link_to` with arguments added:

http://.../posters/new?event_id=53 rather than
http://.../posters/new

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> link_to('link text', new_poster_url(:event_id => event.id))

You could also take a look at nested resources for alternative URL mapping.

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you use named routes or use a hash of options, but both are straightforward.

```
<%= link_to @post.title, {:controller => 'posts', :action => "show", :some_param => "some params"} %>
```

And if you have named_rotes which are coming from `map.resources` or whatever you can do it this way:

```
<%= link_to @post.title, post_path(:some_param => 'some param') %>
```

Then you can access these params in your controller:

```
def show
   some_param = params[:some_params]
end
```